# Django Forms and Buttons

Tags: django, forms, button

I have been working on forms only recently and I am still puzzeld by them.

What I want are standard Forms:

1. Next Button
2. Submit Data to Db
3. Timestamp
4. Clickable Images with Regions defined where when I click I get to the next page

And

I would like to combine these.

E.g. have a next button + Record the Timestamp.
or
E.g. Click into an Image + Next + Timestamp

If anybody could give me some examples for code that can achieve that or a good online resource on where to get info on that, that would be awesome.

Thanks for the time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're trying to move data from an HTML form to the database, I'd suggest looking at how to use [ModelForms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). In a nutshell, you create a model class, like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then you create a ModelForm class that references that model:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

You can render an instance of MyModelForm in a view function. Inside of a POST request in that view, you bind the POST data to the form, validate it, and call save() on it to commit it to the database:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        model_instance = form.save()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for that. I will try to implement that immediately!!

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a question, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.

If you want to use Django forms, start [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), or [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter07/).

I assume the stuff you mention about a timestamp should probably be an auto_now field in a model.  Take a look at [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield).

The stuff you mention about buttons and click-able images is really just HTML and has nothing to do with Django.  I would try [Google](http://www.google.com) for that.